# Get an object in array by one of its fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Sorry I'm kind of new to JS; I have an array of object; how can I get the name of the object which has the key "user_key3" and obviously without having a loop and have a condition.

```
arr = [{
        "name": "user1",
        "key": "user_key1"
},{
        "name": "user3",
        "key": "user_key3"
},{
        "name": "user2",
        "key": "user_key2"
}]
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification

Thanks

Comment: I have given the same answer as the accepted one long before that answer was posted. Any reason to overlook my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inefficient yet concise solution would be

```
var keyarr = arr.map(function(x) { return x.key } );
//keyarr is list of keys
var index=keyarr.indexOf("user_key3");
//arr[index] is your answer. Index will be -1 if the key doesn't exist
```

Comment: @pasargad - you wanted name of object, while this solution gives you just the location

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to iterate and check for the key

```
var user_name;

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if ( arr[i].key === 'user_key3' ) {
        user_name = arr[i].name;
        break;
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p89D7/)

You've edited the question to include

> obviously without having a loop and have a condition

but a loop and a condition is by far the most efficient and cross-browser way to do this, so why would you "obviously" not want this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the functional way, like this

```
var name;
arr.forEach(function(currentObject) {
    if (currentObject.key === "user_key3") {
        name = currentObject.name;
    }
});
```

If you want to short-circuit on the first match, you can use `Array.prototype.some`, like this

```
var name;
arr.some(function(currentObject) {
    if (currentObject.key === "user_key3") {
        name = currentObject.name;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP had mentioned **obviously without having a loop and have a condition**. I would do it as below:

```
arr = [{
    "name": "user1",
    "key": "user_key1"
},{
    "name": "user3",
    "key": "user_key3"
},{
    "name": "user2",
    "key": "user_key2"
}];

var keyValMap = arr.map(function(n) { return n.key } );
var arrIndex = keyValMap.indexOf('user_key3');
alert(arr[arrIndex].name);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b33LU/)**

Answer (score 1):

In general, finding an item that satisfies some arbitrary property in an array requires you to loop over the array:

```
function find(arr, name) {
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if ( arr[i].key === name ) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Then to find it,

```
var obj = find(arr, 'user_key3');
```

Using more functional solutions to find the item is fine too, but you still end up looping in some way.

However, if you are doing lookups by key, then an array of key-value pairs is not the best data structure. I would suggest using an object directly:

```
var map = {
  'user_key1': 'user1',
  'user_key2': 'user2',
  'user_key3': 'user3'
}
```

Then lookup is simply:

```
map['user_key3'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#where)

For Your Example -

```
_.where(arr, {key: "user_key3"});
```

Comment: This is not internally javascript. This is like making a loop in a custom function and then use and call that function...

Comment: Yeah it's quite True.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do such thing with Objects in Javascript. Though here you have a combination of callbacks and loop:

```
arr = [{
        "name": "user1",
        "key": "user_key1"
  },{
        "name": "user3",
        "key": "user_key3"
},{
        "name": "user2",
        "key": "user_key2"
}];

arr.forEach(function(elme){

   for(var g in elme)
   {  
     if(elme[g] == 'user_key3') 
     {
       console.log("Found the value: "+g+" : "+elme[g]);
     };
   }
});
```